# SQL: select data which doesn't have relations in another table

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm writing a C# application and am using an Access .mdb. I have a table with email messages and a table with message relations (each email msg can be assigned to several teams of workers).

I want to to get messages from the first table which are NOT assigned to any team - ie, either have no entries in the second table or have an empty entry. It works ok with empty entries but doesn't return rows which don't have that assignment entry at all.

I'm using the following query:

```sql
SELECT TOP 10 Mails.* 
FROM Mails INNER JOIN MailAssignments ON Mails.msgId = MailAssignments.msgId 
    WHERE (Mails.msgId <= ?)
    AND
    (Mails.msgId NOT IN (SELECT msgId FROM MailAssignments))
    OR (MailAssignments.forTeam IS NULL)
    OR (MailAssignments.forTeam = '')
```

*UPDATE:*

I NEED to use some kind of JOIN because on some conditions the query should also return rows having a relation in the other table (eg. when someone wants to display messages from their team AND unassigned messages).

*UPDATE:*

OK, I guess I can make it simplier by deleting any assignment from the second table so that I don't need to check the empty assignments, only the ones that don't exist at all. But I still need to sometimes show data which is assigned ALONG WITH data which has not been assigned. And I need to build one query for that which will only have different parameters changed :/

*UPDATE / SOLUTION:*

I did some more adjustments but LEFT JOIN basically did the trick for me! Thanks for that hint and all your help, guys!

Comment: Update: You cannot really have messages from their team for mails that are not assigned to a team, can you?

Comment: I want workers to see their team's messages by default but when they enable other views they are supposed to see also unassigned messages (so they can then assign them to their team for example)

Comment: I did some more adjustments but LEFT JOIN basically did the trick for me! Thanks for your help, guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be enough:

```sql
SELECT TOP 10 Mails.* 
FROM Mails 
    WHERE (Mails.msgId <= ?)
    AND
    (Mails.msgId NOT IN (SELECT msgId FROM MailAssignments))
```

Reading your description, it seems tha you may have rows in `MailAssignments` that are related to `Mails` but a team has not really be assigned (the `forTeam` column has an empty string. This is not good design but in this case, use this:

```sql
SELECT TOP 10 Mails.* 
FROM Mails 
  LEFT JOIN 
     MailAssignments ON Mails.msgId = MailAssignments.msgId
WHERE (Mails.msgId <= ?)
  AND (  (MailAssignments.forTeam IS NULL)
      OR (MailAssignments.forTeam = '')
      )
```

Comment: With the caveat that you may get more than 10 records returned, because Access returns matches. You can work around this by including a unique column (field) in the Order By statement.

Comment: It's OK for me. Most important is that the other conditions work correctly (including the JOIN keyword)

Answer (score 2):

Join `Mails` to the subset of `MailAssignments` trying to match mails with existing assignments (where `forTeam <> ''`) and picking those where no match has taken place:

```sql
SELECT TOP 10
  Mails.*
FROM Mails
  LEFT JOIN MailAssignments ON Mails.msgId = MailAssignments.msgId
    AND MailAssignments.forTeam <> ''
WHERE Mails.msgId <= ?
  AND MailAssignments.msgId IS NULL /* either no match for this mail at all
                                       or no match with an existing assignment
                                       – so, just no match */
```

Comment: The `MailAssignments.forTeam <> ''` is cancelled this way, isn't it?

Comment: @ypercube: Yes, the query is supposed to return rows where a `Mails` row doesn't have a `MailAssignments` match at all or its match has an empty `forTeam` value (either `''` or `NULL`).

Comment: @ypercube: Actually I forgot to specify what exactly should be returned. :) Updated the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Because you used the join I guess you need columns from the 2nd table, use an `OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` (it returns entries on the table without a match in the join).

If you do not need them I agree with @ypercube.